# Homotopy limits in $\mathsf{Top}$ (and Postnikov towers)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am a little bit confused about (sequencial) homotopy limits, since I think I found contradictory statements. The working example I have in mind is the Postnikov tower $(P_n X)_n$ of a space $X$. Replacing the maps $P_n X \to P_{n-1}X$ by fibrations, we have that the canonical map $X  \to \lim P_n X$ is a weak homotopy equivalence. But this is somehow related with taking a homotopy limit instead, and that's what I am trying to understand.

According to [Source A](http://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Eguillou/S11/527-Week11.pdf) (p. 3) and [Source A'](http://uregina.ca/%7Efranklam/Math527/Math527_HW11_sol.pdf) (p. 3), the slogan is "a homotopy limit is what you get by replacing every map by a fibration and later taking the usual limit". This agrees with the picture for homotopy pullbacks.

According to Source B = Hatcher (p. 462), the homotopy limit consists of an explicit construction with points and a path for every map in the diagram. The author actually adds:

> In the case of a diagram $··· \to X_2 \to X_1$ such as a Postnikov tower this
> construction gives something slightly different from simply turning
> each successive map into a fibration via the usual pathspace
> construction, starting with  $X_2 \to X_1$ and proceeding up the tower, as we
> did in §4.3.

Hence Source B contradicts Source A and A'. What  am I missing? Do they mean different notions of "homotopy limit"? And if so, in what sense is $X$ weak homotopy equivalent to a homotopy limit according to Hatcher's notion?

Comment: When Hatcher write `slightly different' he means that the point sets differ (and that maybe the two spaces are not even homeomorphic). The point is that the two constructions agree up to weak equivalence, and this is sufficient for homotopical considerations.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a reference for that? Actually,  there is an exercise in Hatcher stating that, for a sequencial homotopy colimit, the mapping telescope is homotopy equivalent to the "infinite mapping construction" aka replace (inductively) every map by a cofibration. Since my question deals with the dual construction, should I expect that both homotopy limits (as I described them in the question) are homotopy equivalent (so not only weak as you mentioned)?